# Jquery Plugin doesn't work with Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

The page1.php is calling Ajax to get Treeview from page2.php (The reason why use Ajax here, because the Treeview changed based on the db). The Treeview is a Jquery plugin here. Thus, all required the Jquery library for Treeview have been imported in the page1.php.

However, the Jquery library doesn't triggered. The `console.log($("#browser").treeview());` is showing the empty Jquery().

Is there anyone can help me? Many thanks!

**--Ajax part in Page 1---**

```
<head>

<script src="jquery.treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){


            $("#browser").treeview();

            console.log($("#browser").treeview());  
            //show Jquery()-means the jquery.treeview didn't called


        });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showTreeview()
            {

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                       document.getElementById("treemenu").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("POST","page2.php",true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="treemenu">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is the #browser element? I don't see it in your markup.

Comment: #browser element is in the page2.php

Comment: Your example is incomplete, so it's hard to say what's going on. I don't see any code that will call the showTreeview () function, so I'm not sure why that's even in this example. As ShankarSangoli said, if #browser is in page2.php, you need to instantiate the treeview from that page. You can use $(document).ready (); inside that page to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `#browser` element anywhere in the markup you provided. If it is part of `page2.php` then you should execute the treeview plugin once the content is loaded on the page.

When jQuery gives empty set that means it did not find any element matching the selector.